# How to move item to top and bottom of selectlist using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set options to move to top or bottom of the list. Any thoughts on how to get this using jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
    var $op = $('#select2 option:selected'),
      $this = $(this);
    if ($op.length) {
      ($this.val() == 'Up') ?
      $op.first().prev().before($op):
        $op.last().next().after($op);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="select2">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Up">
<input type="button" value="Down">
<input type="button" value="Top">
<input type="button" value="Bottom">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
    var $op = $('#select2 option:selected'),
      $this = $(this);
    console.log($this.val())
    if ($op.length) {
      if ($this.val() == 'Top') {
        $('#select2').prepend($op)
      }else if ($this.val() == 'Bottom') {
        $('#select2').append($op)
      }else if ($this.val() == 'Up') {
       $op.prev().before($op);
      }else if ($this.val() == 'Down') {
        $op.next().after($op);
      }

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="select2">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Up">
<input type="button" value="Down">
<input type="button" value="Top">
<input type="button" value="Bottom">
```

Use [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to move top

> Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the beginning of each element in the set of matched elements.

Use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to move bottom

> Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: your snippet doesn't work, but your answer is correct

Comment: @AminJafari it does select 1 and click bottom it will put it to bottom

Comment: by clicking up it goes to top where it should move one step up, if you click down nothing happens, if you click top nothing happens and if you click bottom it works as it should

Comment: @AminJafari sorry about that just wrong word fixed it.. check demo

Comment: I was working on your code. I just resolved when you made the edit. :D
Btw, nice code :)

Comment: @guradio its still not working. The top and bottom seem to work but the up down doesnt seem to work

Comment: because the OP said top and bottom only i didnt work on the up and down lol @AminJafari

Comment: @AminJafari check the update it has up and down as well

Comment: Top-Bottom is working fine and Up-Down does not seem to work when select multiple records , so i did the changes on @guradio's answer, (from reference of questioner's demo)